# Sort numpy matrix based on a comparator function

Tags: python, numpy

I have a vector `v` and a matrix `M`. I want to sort `M` row-wise by comparing each row to `v` with Euclidean distance (`np.linalg.norm`) and sort from least distance to greatest distance. I've looked into `np.argsort` but am not sure how to apply it to this instance or if it even works here. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Example input:

```
k = 5
n = 3
M = np.random.randn(k, n)
v = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: You might produce a fully reproducible example by seeding the random number generator and providing the expected output ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You first have to compute the distances of all rows to that given row. That you can do for example by subtracting the and computing the norm of the resulting rows. After that, you can sort the resulting distance vector using `argsort` which returns the indices that sort the vector in descending order. Finally, you use those indices to index into your original array and get back a sorted ones.

```py
distances = np.linalg.norm(M-np.array(v)[:,None],axis=1)
M_sorted = M[np.argsort(distances),:]
```